# nodejs screenshot-desktop return ENOENT error with pkg module

Tags: node.js

I using 'screenshot-desktop' module for save screenshot as base64. And convert exe using 'pkg' module.

On request screenshot at converted exe file, my program is throw this error

```json
{
    "message": {
        "errno": -4058,
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "syscall": "spawn C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
        "path": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
        "spawnargs": ["/d", "/s", "/c", "\"\"C:\\snapshot\\Client\\node_modules\\screenshot-desktop\\lib\\win32\\screenCapture_1.3.2.bat\" \"C:\\Users\\bass9030\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\20211030-70756-1m04nwl.8l9w.jpg\" \""],
        "cmd": "\"C:\\snapshot\\Client\\node_modules\\screenshot-desktop\\lib\\win32\\screenCapture_1.3.2.bat\" \"C:\\Users\\bass9030\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\20211030-70756-1m04nwl.8l9w.jpg\" "
    }
}
```

But if run js file as node.exe, [It works normally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9pIh.png)

Here is my source code and package.json file

app.js

```js
screenshot({foramt:'jpg'}).then((img) => {
    server.emit('sendshot', {
        base64: img.toString('base64')
    });
}).catch(e => {
    server.emit('Error', {message: e});
})
```

package.json(only pkg config)

```json
{
    "bin": {
        "app": "./app.js"
    },
    "pkg": {
        "assets": [
            "node_modules/screenshot-desktop/lib/win32/screenCapture_1.3.2.bat",
            "node_modules/screenshot-desktop/lib/win32/app.manifest"
        ],
        "scripts": "./app.js",
        "targets": [
            "node16-win-x64"
        ],
        "outputPath": "dist"
    }
}
```

So how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issues with using https://github.com/bencevans/screenshot-desktop/pull/225